# Deploying ejbs in a war, ear or adding it to the lib directory of the app server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0

I have web application which has a servlet and an ejb. The ejb is annotated @Local. In my servlet I used @Inject to inject the ejb. It woekd fine.

Then I created an ear with an ejb module and a web module. I deployed the ear and I got exceptions. Then I learned that I cannot use @Inject. So I used @Resource(lookup = "jndiname") and then it worked.

Then I created an independent web application and used the @Resource annotation to inject the ejb in the ear into a servlet. The war failed to load. So I thought to place the ejb jar inside the lib directory of the app server so that all applications in the app server can use them. I am using jboss eap 6.0. I placed the jar under jbosshome/modules/com/ejb/beginner/main/. It did not work. I got exceptions. Then I placed the ejb jar in jbosshome/modules/com/ejb/beginner/api/main/. Still no luck.

I want to learn how to create @Local beans so that applications in the app server can use. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. If I want to use modules from another ear in other deployments I have to declare the dependencies in the MANIFEST.MF file like this

Dependencies: deployments.appname.ear.appname.jar

The following links help me figure it out

https://community.jboss.org/message/604576
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7